# Venturing into Investment Market

Tags: investing, india, financial-literacy, cryptocurrency, books

What are some of the noted and best *books* which cover the basics of Stock market, Forex, Bitcoin investment and other investment concepts and provide expertise and in-depth knowledge of the same? Also it would be helpful if those books are available globally as well. Please provide the best list possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for best books that cover the basics as well as provide expertise and in-depth knowledge of the same.  Those are two different creatures because books that address complexity tend to skip the basics since it's assumed that in order to understand sophisticated analysis, strategies, etc. then you need to already know the basics.

In addition, there are many areas of investing and trading so there's  a wide range of topics:

Technical analysis

Fundamental analysis

Commodities

Single Stock Futures

Shorting

Investing in stocks, bonds, Pfd stocks, ETFs, mutual funds, CEFs, even Bitcoin

Annuities

Options

To some degree, what the best books are is somewhat subjective.  To see that, simple Google: "Best Investment Books".  There are many lists with some degree of overlap but certainly, no definitive one size fits all list.  As a result, opinions on how to invest and what to invest in are as plentiful as the day is long and what suits one may not suit another.

My simplest advice to read everything that you can about the financial markets. Start with beginner level introductory material. There are a lot of "XYZ For Dummies" books.  Build a basic foundation of financial literacy.  From there, move up the food chain.  As you understand more, seek out the more complex books in areas of the market that interest you. Once you understand more than just the basics, you'll be able to scan the index or review of a book and judge for yourself if it will add to your understanding of the market segment that interests you.